# Raytracer 2D Light Model broken

Tags: glsl, raytracing

Im trying to implement a little 2d-raytracer for education and art purposes.
But there seems to be a bug in my lightmodel code.

[image: Bug Picture]
As you can see one site of the line is appearing much brighter than the other one.

Here's the rendering code:
[RENDERING CODE GLSL](https://github.com/schwenk/2D-RaytracerGLSL/blob/master/fshader.glsl)

I think the cause could probably be the random number generator, but i'm not shure and don't know how to proof this.

Edit: But sometimes I'm getting quite good results like this:
[image: good result]

I used this pice of code for the Ray Line - Intersection.
[Ray Line - Intersection](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/85850/collision-intersection-of-2d-ray-to-line-segment)

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug in the code here:

```
public static Vector2? lineSegmentIntersection(Vector2 r0, Vector2 r1, Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
    Vector2 s1, s2;
    s1 = r1; // FOR A RAY IT HAS TO LOOK LIKE THIS !
    s2 = b - a;

    float s, t;
    s = (-s1.Y * (r0.X - a.X) + s1.X * (r0.Y - a.Y)) / (-s2.X * s1.Y + s1.X * s2.Y);
    t = (s2.X * (r0.Y - a.Y) - s2.Y * (r0.X - a.X)) / (-s2.X * s1.Y + s1.X * s2.Y);

    if (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1)
    {
        // Collision detected
        // Return the point of intersection
        return new Vector2(r0.X + (t * s1.X), r0.Y + (t * s1.Y));
    }

    return null; // No collision
}
```